# Find volume of the solid revolved around $y=4$

Tags: calculus, solid-of-revolution

Consider the function $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x}$

The region is bounded by $y=0$ and $x=0$

So I write the integral as so
$$ \pi \int_0^44^2-(\sqrt{1-x})^2dx$$
Solving it gives the answer $68\pi$

I don't have the answer given in the back of my textbook and I was wondering if I setup the integral correctly.

Comment: You can't integrate from $0$ to $4$ since $0\leq x \leq 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral with the washer method should be

$$ \pi \int_0^1 [4^2-(4-\sqrt{1-x})^2]dx$$

where 4 and $4-\sqrt{1-x}$ are the outer and inner radius of the ring, respectively. Note that the integral is over $x$, which has its upper bound $x=1$ given by $0=\sqrt{1-x}$.

Answer (score 1):

Using cylindrical shells you end up with an easier integral. The
formula is

$$
\int_0^1 2 \pi ( 4 - y) (1 - y^2) dy = \frac{29 \pi}{6}
$$

Note the following. The cylindrical shell is seated on the y
axis. Therefore the radius $r$, height $h$ and thickness of the
cylindrical shell respectively are:

$$
r = (4 - y), \quad h = (1 - x) \quad \text{and}\; \mathrm{thickness} = dy
$$

Since the eventual integral is going to be in terms of $dy$ we need to
solve for $x$ in the equation for $h$. We get $x = 1 - y^2$. Once
again our integral is in terms of $y$. So our bounds on the integral
too needs to be in terms of $y$. The bounds on $y$ are $0$ and $1$.

Note that this gives the same answer as that of @Quanto. His/her solution
requires that you expand the term $(4 - \sqrt{1 -x})^2$. Which results
in quite a nasty integral that still has a square root term in it.

Drawing a picture and trying to figure out the various radii, heights
and thicknesses (if you are using cylindrical shells) helps.